# How to have input with label in React Native Web (Expo)

Tags: accessibility, expo, react-native-web

Im using React Native Web in Expo. Ive read that it does accessibility properly however I can't see how to have a label for the input:

```
  <TextInput
    style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
    value={this.state.text}
  />
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.53/textinput

For clarification and because it's weird name, I'm using React Native Web not React DOM:

https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special, you can just wrap the `<textInput>` in a label as you would with any input.

Your code still outputs HTML at the end of the day.

Something along the lines of (I don't know React so just use this is an example)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class UselessTextInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: 'Useless Placeholder' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <label>Text Label
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
      /></label>
    );
  }
}

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => UselessTextInput);
```

As you are using React I presume you have no need to support Internet Explorer 8 and below so wrapping an input in a label will work correctly with all screen reader and browser combinations.

If for any reason you do need to support the ancient stuff then you need to create an `id` on the input so you can use `for="itemID"` on the label. (the `for` on the label should contain the `id` of the input). Please note that you need to wrap them in a `<div>` if you do this due to the way React works.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class UselessTextInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: 'Useless Placeholder' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
    <label for='itemID'>Text Label</label>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
        id="itemID"
      /></div>
    );
  }
}

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => UselessTextInput);
```

Finally you can add `aria` as you would any other property

```
render() {
    return (
    <label>Text Label
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
        aria-labelledby="id(s)OfElement(s)ToLabelThisInput"
      /></label>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It's a confusing name, but Im using React Native Web, not React DOM: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

Comment: I literally followed the code example that is on the page you linked to in your question, it also passed validation there so although I may have picked the wrong React version I don't see why the above won't work? Is there something particular about React Native Web I need to be aware of? As far as I can see you still return the HTML you want as part of a component so surely you can just include a `<label>` within that component?

Comment: I am aware you may initialise everything differently but look at the part I am returning within the 'render' function - you can use standard HTML elements I am sure with any flavour of React.

Comment: There is a pull request for adding `accessibilityLabelledBy` here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/32470. As long as I understood it, this is implemented in react-native release 0.69.0-rc.3. I would say, this then would be a solution for this issue.